# VLC Player iPad Pro playback glitch

Tags: ipados, vlc

On VLC Player iPad Pro, when I pause and re-play, for a second the video has no sound.

I have the last beta version of iPadOS, but this problem was there even before that.

How do I fix this? VLC seems to be the last version too.